# MongoDB kills immortal cursors

Tags: php, mongodb, cursor

I'm using PHP mongodb/mongodb driver v 1.1.2

Low-level driver info:

```
mongodb version => 1.1.7
mongodb stability => stable
libmongoc version => 1.3.5
libbson version => 1.3.5
```

MongoDB 3.4.7 and 3.4.10

Connection options:

```
socketTimeoutMS=3600000
```

Cursor options:

```
maxTimeMs: 360000
noCursorTimeout: true
```

So I assume that cursor must be immortal

The program was running normally, then it crashed with the following error:

```
[29-Nov-2017 15:23:04 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException: Cursor not found (namespace: 'xxxx.yyyy', id: 6220790657981310420).
```

In mongos logs I see

```
2017-11-29T15:21:12.025+0000 I QUERY    [ClusterCursorCleanupJob] Marking cursor id 6220790657981310420 for deletion, idle since 2017-11-29T15:11:11.139+0000
2017-11-29T15:21:16.026+0000 I QUERY    [ClusterCursorCleanupJob] Marking cursor id 6220790657981310420 for deletion, idle since 2017-11-29T15:11:11.139+0000
2017-11-29T15:21:20.026+0000 I QUERY    [ClusterCursorCleanupJob] Marking cursor id 6220790657981310420 for deletion, idle since 2017-11-29T15:11:11.139+0000
...
2017-11-29T15:22:56.029+0000 I QUERY    [ClusterCursorCleanupJob] Marking cursor id 6220790657981310420 for deletion, idle since 2017-11-29T15:11:11.139+0000
2017-11-29T15:23:00.029+0000 I QUERY    [ClusterCursorCleanupJob] Marking cursor id 6220790657981310420 for deletion, idle since 2017-11-29T15:11:11.139+0000
2017-11-29T15:23:04.029+0000 I QUERY    [ClusterCursorCleanupJob] Marking cursor id 6220790657981310420 for deletion, idle since 2017-11-29T15:11:11.139+0000
```

Notice that "idle since" timestamp is identical for all lines. I am pretty sure that program was actively fetching data from that cursor.

I have no exact time when cursor was created, but it happened not earlier than 15:03:35.

The issue is very rare. I have lot of active cursors, some of them lives for hours. This one was cleaned up after 20 minutes

Comment: How do you set cursor options?

Comment: @AlexBlex


    $collection = $client->selectCollection("xxxx", "yyyy")->withOptions([
        'maxTimeMS' => 3600000,
        'noCursorTimeout' => true
    ]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only supported **Collection** options are

- readConcern
- readPreference
- typeMap
- writeConcern

[DocsRef](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-withOptions/)

`maxTimeMS` and `noCursorTimeout` are options of the **Cursor**. You need to pass them in `find()` and similar commands.

[DocsRef](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-find/)